# Unable to find Butterknife.Action on upgrading the Butterknife version 8.8.1 to version 10.2.0

Tags: android, butterknife

Unable to find Butterknife.Action and ButterKnife.apply on upgrading the Butterknife version 8.8.1 to version 10.2.0

```
error: cannot find symbol
public static final ButterKnife.Action<View> GONE = (view, index) -> view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               ^
  symbol:   class Action
  location: class ButterKnife
```

Comment: It was deprecated in version 10.0.0: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1428

Answer (score 1):

- Batterknife.aply depricated in AndroidX

If you migrate to AndroidX you must use:

in gradle

```
dependencies {

implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0"

annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0" 

...}
```

in class when you have errors

if you use code like this:

```
- ButterKnife.apply(new View[]{ ivImageId,vgSubscribtionsId,vgSubscribersID},

                    (view, value, index) -> view.setVisibility(value), View.INVISIBLE);
```

replace to this for work with AndroidX:

```
- butterknife.Action viewAction = (view, index) -> {

                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            };
            butterknife.ViewCollections.run(new View[]{ ivImageId,vgSubscribtionsId,vgSubscribersID} , viewAction );
```

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are deprecated and no longer available since version 10.0.0: more details [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1428) and [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/commit/8eb5280c4a7dce8f023d7a29585a2417b82a607e).